# How to change iOS app name based on Flutter Flavor?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have 4 flavors for my flutter app and I want to give different app name for each of them. I found some answers about how to do it on Android, but couldn't find anything concrete for iOS.
I tried making changes to product name in build settings and info.plist file, but no luck. Can anyone help ?